# Default security settings for OneNote notebooks created from Planner

Tags: office365

I created a Plan in Office365 Planner with 3 members to manage a new small project. When I open the OneNote notebook tied to this Plan, I notice that this notebook can be edited by "Everyone except external users" (in the list of the Plan members).
How can I prevent this behavior for the Plans I will create later?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: before to add "-1", read carefully the question, it's a real security issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know onenote documets are stored in a Sharepoint library.

You can change permissions there, go to Configuration - Documents library permissions.

Comment: I know but I would like to change the default behavior. When one creates a new Plan, we need to make sure only the members of the Plan members can edit the notebook. "Everyone except external users" must have only a read-only access to the notebook.

Comment: I think that by default a 'Guest' must be invited if you has marked the plan as 'private'.

Comment: I logged as a normal user (I'm admin) and I can't find my department sites.

Comment: Actually, there is no issue with the plan. The problem is with the OneNote settings.